# jmeter dynamically calling an token without hardcoding

Tags: jmeter, token

In JMeter, I want to dynamically call a token , I've mentioned payload in csv file, its taking data from csv file correctly but not showing token anywhere...I'm using http header manager also ,JSON extractor, response assertion.

Tried using csv file but token not showing in the response body... I want to pass that token to other API also.

Answer (score 0):

If you can successfully obtain the token using real browser (or other application) and cannot using JMeter it means that you're not sending the same request as browser does.

1. Make sure that [JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)
2. Compare the requests originated from JMeter and real browser either using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Once you amend JMeter configuration to look exactly like a real browser and will send the same request (or sequence of requests) you will be able to get the token using JMeter.

Comment: I was able to obtain token when I was hardcoding the data, but when I started using csv file, then token stopped obtaining. For the same API, In postman I have only 2 headers, Content-Type: application/JSON, Authorization but value is empty because that same API only is generating token. I have 2 Http Header Manager, 1 is for the API from where it will obtain the token , and then it will pass that for other API Bearer ${token} in Http Header Manager.